# upload image in edit not saving C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a image upload that works fine in the create but does not work in the edit mode. I am not sure if i am missing something or the edit just handles it differently so the code needs to be different.

In MVC we use `@Html.EditorFor` but in this case I was unsure how to do that so I copied what I had from the create statement and it doesn't appear to work.

My CHTML page has this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PartImage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    <input type="file" name="ImageUpload" onchange="ShowPreview(this)" id="ImageUpload" />
    <img src="~/Content/Images/Parts/@Model.PartImage" alt="preview" style="width:100px;background-color:#d3d3d3;" id="imgbrowers" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PartImage, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
 </div>
```

and Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#imgbrowers").hide();
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#imgbrowers').attr('src', e.target.result);
                $("#imgbrowers").show();
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    $('#ImageUpload').change(function (e) {
        readURL(this);
    });
});
```

Then in my post in the controller I have this:

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(Parts parts)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var user = User.Identity.Name;
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Parts partFromDB = db.Parts.Single(x => x.Material == parts.Material);
                partFromDB.DrawingNumber = parts.DrawingNumber;
                partFromDB.Description = parts.Description;
                partFromDB.ExtDescription = parts.ExtDescription;
                partFromDB.PartImage = parts.PartImage;
                partFromDB.Status = parts.Status;
                partFromDB.UpdatedDate = System.DateTime.Now;
                partFromDB.UpdatedBy = User.Identity.Name;

                db.SaveChanges();

                sb.Append("Sumitted");
                return Content(sb.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var key in this.ViewData.ModelState.Keys)
                {
                    foreach (var err in this.ViewData.ModelState[key].Errors)
                    {
                        sb.Append(err.ErrorMessage + "<br/>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            sb.Append("Error :" + ex.Message);
        }


        return Content(sb.ToString());
    }
```

It does not error out, it just does not get the PartImage from the form. I tried adding `value="ImageUpload"` to the input but that didn't help.

Comment: `<img>` does not get posted with the form. You should be looking for ImageUpload.

Comment: What is the data type partFromDB.PartImage?